# unconverted data remains python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python while trying to parse time using strptime. I am getting the error unconverted data remains. Can someone please help identify where I am making mistake

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = "00:00:49.9342733"
>>> duration = datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 3
```

Comment: It looks like it's trying to parse as microseconds, but you actually have 7 digits after the decimal place (1 more than needed)

Comment: The `%f` part expects exactly 6 digits, because it corresponds to microseconds. This is made clear by [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), which clearly shows six-digit example values. And yes, `strptime` does not allow for extra text after the date it's parsing (as would be clear from just about any relevant web search). Sorry to say the solutions for this are hack workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), the `%f` formatting should contains 6 digits (000000-999999).

To fix this, just slice your original string:

```
s = "00:00:49.9342733"[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks. What does [:-1] mean in python?

Comment: Removes the last character of the string. See [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).